# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') (JavaScript array map)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-props

In my React component, I am receiving the props, below is the component. I simply need to grab the props i.e. data and map it and render the data

*Component*

```
import * as React from "react";
    import { Box } from "@chakra-ui/react";
    import CourseCard from "./CourseCard";
    import CourseGrid from "./CourseGrid";
    
    const CardLayout = ({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);
      return (
        <Box
          maxW="7xl"
          mx="auto"
          px={{
            base: "4",
            md: "8",
            lg: "12",
          }}
          py={{
            base: "4",
            md: "8",
            lg: "12",
          }}
        >
          <CourseGrid>
            {data.getPs_courseList.map((course) => (
              <CourseCard key={course.slug} course={course} />
            ))}
          </CourseGrid>
        </Box>
      );
    };

export default CardLayout;
```

*Incoming Props*

```
{
  "getPs_courseList": [
    {
      "short_desc": "JavaScript for Beginners",
      "slug": "javascript_for_beginners",
      "price": "10$",
      "trainer_name": "John",
      "language": "English",
      "level": "Beginner",
      "length_in_minutes": "120"
    },
    {
      "short_desc": "What is GraphQL?",
      "slug": "what_is_graphql",
      "price": "FREE",
      "trainer_name": "Anita",
      "language": "English",
      "level": "Intermediate",
      "length_in_minutes": "230"
    }
  ]
}
```

when I am trying to use the map function like below, I am getting an error. Can anyone suggest what is it I am missing here?

```
 {data.getPs_courseList.map((course) => (
          <CourseCard key={course.slug} course={course} />
        ))}
```

*Error*

[image]

Comment: so `getPs_courseList` is undefined

Comment: If you have `<CardLayout data={someStateValue} />` and `someStateValue` is populated by an API request, the first render happens before that. Meaning you need to initialize `someStateValue` with `{ getPs_courseList: [] }` so it's always an array.

Answer (score 0):

`const CardLayout = ({ data }) => {`

replace with

`const CardLayout = ( data ) => {`

Comment: I just tried this, but the error remains the same.

Comment: If you don't destructure you should call the param `props` (because that's what React passes and you'd have to refer to `props.data`)

Answer (score 0):

Data is always filled? Maybe, when the component is called, data isn't true yet. So you can validate if Data is true before and then run de map method.

```
{ data &&
 data.getPs_courseList.map((course) => (
      <CourseCard key={course.slug} course={course} />
    ))}
```